# boost interprocess file_lock can't lock file it does not own

Tags: c++, boost, locking, interprocess

When I use boost file_lock to try to lock files it doesn't own with lock() or lock_sharable(), it throws an exception.  Is there any way for it to lock a file owned by a different user so it can modify it safely (the modifying user has correct write permissions).

Comment: file_lock is not used for locking files.  It is meant as a cross-process mutex that uses a file to enforce the locking.  It is a lock implemented using a file, and has NOTHING to do with actually locking the file for access.

Comment: yes, i understand what a file lock is in this context. my problem is simply that i cannot lock a file i do not own and would like to know if there are any possible workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you're throwing an exception means that it's not waiting for any existing exclusive or shareable locks to be released (this should be a blocking call).  Make sure that you actually have the file-name correct, or check the error code in the `boost::interprocess_exception` that is being thrown using either the `what()`, `get_native_error()`, or `get_error_code()` methods.  For instance, you could be having a file-permissions problem, or the file may not exist, etc.  An exception is not thrown because of lock contention, so that's not your problem ...

Comment: The error thrown is file permissions.  If we change the owner of the file we want to lock to the user attempting the lock, it works.  Basically, I want two users to be able to lock the file in question, but obviously, only one user can own the file.

Comment: Is there not a group-level permission you can set?  For instance, on Linux/Unix, you can set the owner as well as the read/write/execute accessibility permissions for other users via `chown` and `chmod`.  On Windows you have pretty fine-grained control via ACL's.